# How to build layout in Android without showing it?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to build a `layout` so I can get some parameters out of it (`getLineBounds()` of `TextView`) but until I build the layout, I keep getting 0.
On the other hand I don't want the user to see this layout, Is there any way I can "build" the layout without any user display ?
Thanks

Comment: probably something like `measure(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)` on the view you're interested in.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your answer.

Comment: measure is a method of view. it is called with size parameter to ask the view to layout itself and compute its actual view. if you have the size of your display, you may use that instead of Integer.MAX_VALUE;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. Create your layout in a separate xml file, and use

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_XML)
```

This will just create the view but not display it.

Comment: Nice thinking but still 0 ...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineBounds%28int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29) getLineBounds() returns 0 if the internal Layout has not been built. In order to build the internal Layout you have to measure the view.

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("foo bar");
int widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(500, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(500, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
textView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
int lineBounds = textView.getLineBounds(0, null);
```

Adjust `widthMeasureSpec` and `heightMeasureSpec` to your needs.

Comment: I got height value of "-2147483148" for multiple `TextView` sizes.

Comment: That's strange. What did you you use for `context`? An Activity? On my device this code returns 45...

Comment: I got it to work now, but the returned value isn't the same as my tests (I've tested some screenshots on my device), it returns '24' for text size of `11dp` while I measured 30px.

Comment: Are you looking for getLineHeight() maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your view is onscreen you wont have a width or height attribute other than 0. Your best bet is to throw your views into a framelayout and then you can add an invisible textview ontop of it and then you can get your width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Try `yourlayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

About visibility states you can read here: [View setVisibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

Comment: Yes. You can use `View.GONE` , so it'll not take any place on screen

Comment: Yes. It's just visibility option, it doesn't affect at size.